# Putting \multicolumn in a \forloop => "Misplaced \omit"

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I want to use a `\forloop` to iteratively generate `\multicolumn` commands on the same row, but I'm getting "Misplaced \omit" errors I can't figure out.

The following use of two `\multicolumn` commands on a row, but with no loop, works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Table A, \textbackslash{}multicolumn, but no loop
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|cc|cc|} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This generates the output:
[image]

However, I need to produce the `\multicolumns` iteratively. Here is my attempt: I introduced a new counter, `loopindex`, and created a `\forloop` that runs twice, each time issuing `\multicolumn{2}{c}{A}` followed by a `&`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop}
\newcounter{loopindex}
\begin{document}
Table B, with loop but no \textbackslash{}ifthenelse
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|cc|cc|} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\forloop{loopindex}{1}{\value{loopindex}<3}{\multicolumn{2}{c}{A} &}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This results in the following error: "Misplaced \omit. \multispan -> \omit  \@multispan.

[image]

I realize that my simple loop is throwing off an extra "&" on the second iteration, but (a) I added a fifth column to the `tabular` definition and, alternatively, (b) I added an `ifthenelse` to print the "&" only on the first iteration, so I don't think that the extra "&" is the problem.

What am I doing wrong?

I am open to alternatives to `forloop`, if that's the problem. However, my real application is more demanding than simply repeating the same `\multicolumn` `n` times. I need a loop counter so that I can step through a `arrayjobx` array to get the content to place in each `\multicolumn`.

Comment: The problem has shown several times: `\multicolumn` has to be the first item in a cell, so it cannot appear after “unexpandable” jobs have already been performed.

Comment: @egreg, is there a way to pre-expand the `\forloop` into another variable/command, so that I have `\expandedoutput = \multicolumn{2}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B}`, that I can then put into the `tabular`?

Comment: I'd use neither `forloop` nor `arrayjobx`. If you disclose your aim, probably better solutions can be found.

Comment: @egreg, I'm writing a package to typeset strategic-form games, akin to Martin Osborne's `sgame` package but avoiding its incompatibility with the `array` package. In my case, the document author defines an `m × n` game by filling four `arrayjobx` arrays [`\RowStrategies`, `\ColumnStrategies`, `\RowPayoffs`, and `\ColumnPayoffs` (the latter two of which are 2-dimensional arrays)]. The particular `\multicolumn' issue here is simply to annotate the game matrix with Column's strategies, each of which must span two columns. For my limited purposes, I've found a tedious/inelegant workaround.

Comment: Can you provide sample input?

Comment: @cfr, the only problematic part is the Column player's strategies and these are simply labels, often a single character. So, for example, `\ColumnStrategies(1)={A}`, and similarly "B" through "E", for elements 2, 3, 4, and 5. That's precisely the role of the "A" and "B" in my original MWE. Each needs to be centered within a two-column `\multicolumn{2}{c}{\ColumnStrategies(1)}`. The number of these strategies is small, usually less than 10. I've never seen such a game typeset with more than 10 column strategies.

Comment: Since the number of reasonably possible Column strategies is so small, the workaround I've developed today is, rather than having a `\forloop` in the row itself, use an `\ifcase` to test for the number of Column strategies and then select the appropriate string of `\multicolumn` statements (i.e., one for each Column strategy). This way there are no unexpandable elements in the row itself. (I wrote a separate LaTeX macro, external to my main package, to produce recursively the required `\multicolumn` statements up to the case of 20 strategies.)